# Why does this code not parse without whitespace?

Tags: haskell, monads

So I am learning Monads and was playing around with the following expression:

`[1,2] >>= \x -> ['a','b'] >>= \y -> return (x,y)`

The above code produces the result `[(1,a),(1,b),(2,a),(2,b)]` as expected.

But since I was just experimenting, I got lazy and I entered:

`[1,2]>>=\x->['a','b']>>=\y->return (x,y)` (same code as above but without white-spaces)

which doesn't seem to work.

I understand that if I properly bracket out this expression as

`[1,2]>>=(\x->(['a','b']>>=(\y->return (x,y))))`

it will work (better I just put spaces than these monstrous brackets) but I don't get why the expression with white-space works whereas the other one doesn't.

Comment: I'd think that the reason is that the parser confuses `>>=\` as an entire operator by itself.

Comment: ``>>=\`` gets lexed as one operator token. This is analogous to how `foobar` is different than `foo bar` - just with symbols.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay But `>>=` is indeed an operator, right?

Comment: @Alec Oh, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @kishlaya Yes, I meant `>>=\\` but stackoverflow comments rendered it wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need spaces to separate identifier names: `foo bar` is two separate names, whereas `foobar` (without the space) is just one name.

The same thing happens with operators. Haskell allows arbitrary user-defined operators; if you want to write a function named `??++!?!`, then go for it! But you *must* use spaces to separate operators from one another.

Just as `>>=` is not the same thing as `>> =`, so `>>=\` isn't the same as `>>= \`. You could actually define a function named `>>=\` if you wanted. But the space lets the Haskell language parser know this is two things, not one.

Answer (score 0):

To fully understand this, you need to look at Chapter 2 of the Haskell Report, particularly [section 2.4](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4). The lexeme `->` is a `reservedop`, `>>=` is not.

For example, does this expression require a space, or spaces?

```
[1,2]>>=return 
[1,2] >>=return
```